# Save complicated text column from pandas to csv/Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, csv

I work with text data and I have a df which I want to save to Excel or csv to see actually overall picture (very annoying just to check in in pandas). The problem is that is apparently because my df has uncleaned text (I don't want to clean it significantly at this point, because I might still need it), this df can't be saved to excel. Three of df would look smth like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'journal_lines': ['ASTRONOMY AND ASTROPHYSICS', 'ASTRONOMY AND ASTROPHYSICS', 'ATOMIC AND NUCLEAR PHYSICS'],
    'abstract_lines': ['ABSTRACT 1', 'ABSTRACT 2', 'ABSTRACT 3'],
    'themes_lines': ['(Classical astronomy; Interplanetary and inter...', '(Classical astronomy; Interplanetary and inter...', '(Radiation; Nuclear reactions; Accelerators; S...'],
    'type_document': ['GSFC Document', 'GSFC Document', 'GSFC Document'],
    'document_digit': ['X-611-67-8', 'X-611-67-52', 'X-640-66-514'],
    'document_number': ['GSFC Document X-611-67-8', 'GSFC Document X-611-67-52', 'GSFC Document X-640-66-514'],
    'extracted_text': [
        'A STUDY OF LOW ENERGY GALACTIC\nCOSMIC RAYS FROM 1961 TO 1965\nB. Teegarden January 1967\nThe results from a series of balloon flights\nbeginning in 1961 and ending in 1965 are pre-\nsented. Measurements of the cosmic ray in-\ntensity were made using a dE/dx and E detector\nsensitive to energies from 15to 80 MeV "nucleon.\nThe early balloon flights provided design informa-\ntion and also aided in the development of data\nhandling techniques for later satellite versions\nof the detector which have been on IMP’s I, Il,\nand Ill and OGO’s | and Il. Proton and helium\nintensities at 85 MeV/nucleon are presented for\nthe five year period covered by the balloon flight\nseries. The behavior of the proton to helium\nratio as a function of time is discussed within\nthe framework of Parker’s model for the solar\nmodulation of cosmic rays.\n\nIn 1965 a modified version of the dE/dx and\nE detector with an extended energy range was\nflown for the first time. A cosmic ray helium\nspectrum from 60 to 500 MeV/nucleon measured\nby this detector is presented. The change in\nproton and helium intensities in this energy\nregion from 1963 to 1965 is examined and com-\npared with the results predicted by the various\nspecial cases of Parker’s model.\n\nA totally empirical atmospheric secondary\nproton spectrum is derived, based on simulta-\nneous balloon and satellite measurements. This\n\nGo gle\n\nGSFC DOCUMENTS\n\nspectrum is compared with the secondary spec-\ntrum obtained from a nuclear emulsion measure-\nment and the differences are discussed. Using\nour empirical secondary spectrum, we obtain an\nupper limit for the re-entrant albedo at Sioux\nFalls which is significantly less than values\nreported by other observers.\n\nA measurement of the intensities of secondary\ndeuterium and tritium was made in 1965. Using\nthese results, we obtain a value for the global\naverage production of tritium in the earth’s\natmosphere. The implications of this result\nregarding the problem of tritium balance in the\natmosphere are discussed.\n\n2'
    ],
    'date': ['January 1967', 'February 1967', 'November 1966'],
    'article_name': [
        'A STUDY OF LOW ENERGY GALACTIC\nCOSMIC RAYS FROM 1961 TO 1965\nB. Teegarden January 1967',
        'THE FLUX OF HEAVY NUCLEI IN THE PRI-\nMARY COS... February 1967',
        'EXCITATION OF HYDROGEN MOLECULE BY\nELECTRON I... November 1966'
    ]
})
```

What I tried is to use separator "#" and replace line breaks with "\n"

```
# replace line breaks with "\n"
df['extracted_text'] = df['extracted_text'].str.replace('\n', '\\n')

# save DataFrame to CSV with '#' as separator
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='#', index=False)
```

The code runs. However, it does not help. When I open csv through excel (import as text data, tell separator is #), still it would confuse the abstract with text and put it all over instead of having a structured df.

How can I approach this?

Comment: I tried and failed to load even this example as a dataframe. I suspect that the issues is very likely to be single and double quotes in the text. If these are not escaped properly, it leads to things going in the wrong places (as commas in the text are seen as delimiters if the quotes aren't handled correctly). to_csv has quotechar, which you could specify as single quotes and see if that's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it at least for excel in the end. With csv still don't know, but works somehow with excel and  I guess it is fine...

```
import xlwt

# Create a new workbook and add a sheet
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')

# Write column headers
headers = list(df.columns)
for col_index, header in enumerate(headers):
    sheet.write(0, col_index, header)

# Write data rows
for row_index, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), start=1):
    for col_index, value in enumerate(row[1:], start=0):
        sheet.write(row_index, col_index, str(value))

# Save the workbook to an Excel file
workbook.save('output.xls')
```